# interfaces and classes in C#

Tags: c#, class, interface, repository

I get the following error:

> test.Services.JobService' does not contain a constructor that takes
>   0 arguments.

this is the code:

JobService.cs:

```
namespace TesteUltrafan.Services
{
    public class JobService
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public JobService(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public Job CreateJobBanker()
        {
            var banker = new Job();

            string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

            Console.WriteLine("Novo job banker id: {0}", id);

            banker.Id = id;
            banker.Type = JobType.Banker;
            banker.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine("Salvando job banker id: {0}", id);

            Job jobBanker = _repository.SaveJob(banker);

            return jobBanker;
        }
    }
}
```

the program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jobService = new JobService(); <---- Here is the error.

        Console.WriteLine("Creating job banker, creation:");

        Job jobBanker = jobService.CreateJobBanker();

        Console.WriteLine("Job banker: {0}", jobBanker);
    }
}
```

Job.cs:

```
public class Job
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public JobType Type { get; set; }
}
```

JobType.cs:

```
public enum JobType
{
    Actor = 1,
    Agricultural = 2,
    Banker = 3,
    EngineerCivil = 4,
    Another = 5,
}
```

Comment: Default constructor is missing.

Comment: this is the IRepository:

public interface IRepository
    {
        Job SaveJob(Job job);

    }

Answer (score 8):

You either need to create a parameterless constructor in your `JobService` class (which I would not do because then your class will not work correctly - there will be no reference to any repository)  or preferably pass a Repository instance as a parameter when constructing this instance.

So the code should preferably look like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jobService = new JobService(new Repository()); 

        Console.WriteLine("Creating job banker, creation:");

        Job jobBanker = jobService.CreateJobBanker();

        Console.WriteLine("Job banker: {0}", jobBanker);
    }
}
```

Where `Repository` should be a class implementing `IRepository` interface. Without passing this instance your `CreateJobBanker` will not work.

What would be though recommended is to use some IoC Container, because your code follows the Inversion of Control principle (probably you are not even aware of this).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var jobService = new JobService(new Repository());
```

because otherwise your `JobService` with not have an `IRepository` instance and will throw a `NullReferenceException` when you try to use your repository inside `JobService`.

In your code, you are initialising `JobService` without giving it a `IRepository` argument, to get your code to compile you need to define a constructor in `JobService` that does not have an `IRepository` argument if you want to do that:

```
public class JobService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    // New Constructor will make _repository null
    public JobService()
    {           
    }

    public JobService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Job CreateJobBanker()
    {
        var banker = new Job();

        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

        Console.WriteLine("Novo job banker id: {0}", id);

        banker.Id = id;
        banker.Type = JobType.Banker;
        banker.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("Salvando job banker id: {0}", id);

        // NullReferenceException if you define a parameterless constructor
        Job jobBanker = _repository.SaveJob(banker);

        return jobBanker;
    }
}
```

Now you can construct it in two ways:

```
var jobService = new JobService();
```

or

```
var jobService = new JobService(new Repository());
```

`IRepository` implementation:

```
public class Repository: IRepository
{
   private MyDbEntities context = new MyDbEntities();

   public Job SaveJob(Job job)
   {
       // assuming Entity Framework
       var id = job.Id;
       if (context.Jobs.Any(e => e.Id == id))
       {
           context.Jobs.Attach(job);
           context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(jobs, EntityState.Modified);
       }
       else
       {
           context.Jobs.AddObject(myEntity);
       }

       context.SaveChanges();
       return job;
   }
}
```

Comment: but then it gives this error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'test.Repositories.IRepository'

Comment: You need to implement IRepository. I will update my answer with an example implementation. Pass in the implementation, not the Interface. You cannot instantiate an interface, that's what your second error means.